# Foeach loop duplicate values mysql

Tags: php

When the form is submitted values are inserted into a mysql database. I am using a `foreach` loop for fetching the results but I am getting unnecessary duplicate results displayed. The results are being displayed from three tables: `academy`, `courses_by_academy` and `person`.  They all share a foreign key `academy_id`. How can I display the information just once without having to show up twice?

Please check this working [DEMO](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/courses.php) for better understanding. Make sure to choose more than two courses and two contact/instructor person to see this specific behavor.

```
$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT a.name, 
       a.academy_id,
       ca.course_name,
       ca.course_start_date,
       ca.course_end_date,
       p.contact_role,
       p.instructor_role,
       p.first_name,
       p.last_name,
       p.person_email,
       p.person_phone,
       p.person_fax
FROM academy a
INNER JOIN courses_by_academy ca ON a.academy_id = ca.academy_id
INNER JOIN person p ON a.academy_id = p.academy_id
WHERE a.academy_id = :acad_id
");
if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array(':acad_id' => $acad_id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    $final_result = '';
    $first = true;
    foreach ($results as $value){
        if($first){
          $first = false;
          $final_result .= "<b>Academy Name: </b>".$value['name']."<b>  ID: </b>".$value['academy_id']."</br>";
        }
          $final_result .= "-------------------COURSES_OFFERED------------------</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['course_start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['course_end_date']."</br>";
          $final_result .= "---------------------PERSONEL-----------------------</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>First Name: </b>".$value['first_name']."</br><b>Last Name: </b>".$value['last_name']."</br><b>Email: </b>".$value['person_email']."</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>This person has the role of an instructor: </b>".$value['instructor_role']."</br><b>This person has the role of a contact: </b>".$value['contact']."</br>";
          $final_result .= "<b>Phone: </b>".$value['person_phone']."</br><b>Fax: </b>".$value['person_fax']."</br>";        
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the extra ? So what do you want to be showed just once ?

Comment: Give us output example now and example of what the output should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick run through your demo, I could only select up to two courses, not more than.

From what I can see the select statement is all processing logically as set out in your code.

As a matter of fact, your if statement already answers this requirement.  EG:

```
if($first){
      $first = false;
      $final_result .= "<b>Academy Name: </b>".$value['name']."<b>  ID: </b>".$value['academy_id']."</br>";
    }
```

This works perfectly in your demo only showing the academy name once.  Why not use this wherever you need it?

The only thing I think you don't really need is to display the second personell entry.  You could use the same concept to hide that after the first record.